# Does a main class that implements something violate Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: java, oop

Does a main class that implements something violate Single Responsibility Principle?
For example, see this from the Java tutorials at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
    }

}
```

In this example, does HelloRunnable violate the Single Responsibility Principle? Rather, is this a kludge?

EDIT: pretend this is a real life case (not a tutorial example)--what do you think in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `main` method in general does not really fit very well into the "single responsibility principle". But it also does not really violate it. A program always needs some kind of entry point to launch it - in Java thats a `main` method. You are right in the sense that the code inside that `main` method does not really belong into this class. A way around this that I have often seen is the creation of a "special" class that provides nothing else than the entry point. For example you could extend this tutorial to:

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
    }
}
```

But as the source of your question is a tutorial, noone cares about much about design principles. One tends to keep the code as small and simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is no real world example. Normally you would divide up functionality on several (single responsible) classes. But this would have cluttered this example listing and would have mislead from the intention. And you could argue, that saying hello is the single responsibility of this class ;)

Comment: Right, it's not a real world example. Actually I provided this example because I was about to do this in real life. But then I thought twice about it and hence am asking the question. Basically, I'll avoid ever instantiating an instance of my main class.